# Changing SalesforceDX CLI errors language

Tags: salesforcedx

We are playing with SFDX CLI and when something fails, we have hard time in understanding what went wrong because the errors are not in English and we can't search forums. Is there a way to change the SFDX CLI language?

Comment: can you post an example? what is your OS/ OS language?

Comment: In case if those are errors, returned from SF server, then those are your SF User language

Comment: You are right, it seems to be the locale of my profile

Comment: @kurunve you may like to add your comment as an answer here.

Comment: Although our primary sf instance and the dev hub is in English, our scratch orgs are not in the right language. How can we fix it?